# how to display only + and - in the mapbox navigation control

Tags: mapbox

I am using the following code line to show a navigation control on my map:

```
  map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
```

It displays the Zoom in + and Zoom out - options which are great but it also shows the tilt map option underneath the zoom in and zoom out buttons. I want to remove this and only show Zoom in and Zoom out option. It seems like something simple to fix but I wasn't able to come up with an anser in my research.

Answer (score 14):

They added the feature to disable the compass.
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#navigationcontrol

EDIT:
you can write it like this

```
var nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl({
        showCompass: false,
        showZoom: true
      });

map.addControl(nav, "top-left");
```

Answer (score 2):

[Looks like](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1929) the Mapbox GL JS team is planning on adding the ability to the `mapboxgl.Navigation()` function to disable the compass, but for now, disabling it in the CSS is the preferred way to do it:

```
.mapboxgl-ctrl-compass {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: It works :) Good trick to use while Mapbox does not provide a native way to turn off.